# NCPFS on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04

It's the 19th of may, 2015. I've dug all over the internet trying to find out where to get ncpfs. I need to mount my student share at my high school and it runs on Novell. I've read that it uses a drive service called NCP, and I've also heard that Ubuntu *ONCE* made ncpfs to mount ncp drives. I've tried installing the saucy repository and its reporting that it cant find saucy. I've dug more than a mole and I cant find the answer. Can somebody give me their backup package or something? Thanks!

Oh and did i mention ubuntu is running off of my flash drive?

Answer (score 0):

to get ncpmount up and running I went to https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ncpfs/2.2.6-7/+build/1697927

Then I got the deb's for the following:
libpam-ncp_2.2.6-7_amd64.deb
libncp_2.2.6-7_amd64.deb
ncpfs_2.2.6-7_amd64.deb

I installed them with Software Center in the order I listed above.  ncpmount was then available in terminal